# Java HttpServlet not getting GET/POST from backbone.js

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, servlets, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js and front end development. Appologies if my question is stupid. I searched over google and stackoverflow and didn't get an answer. Here is my question. As I am using backbone for the front end and java for my back end, I am trying to backbone's collections.fetch(), and save(), etc to talk to the Java Servlet. The model is as simple as this:

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
       title: '',
       completed: false
   }
});

    var TodosCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,
    url: '/todo'
});

var todos = new TodosCollection();
todos.fetch();
```

I have in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>todo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.web.TodoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>todo</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/todo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And for TodoServlet.java, I simply have the following code just to check if it gets GET and POST:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{  
     logger.debug("In /todo: doGet");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{  
     logger.debug("In /todo: doPost");
}
```

When I run this on Tomcat and open the webpage, it seems the server is not getting GET. Is this a right way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend using the webdeveloper tools with your browser to view the background call. Also there is firebug if you are not using a browser that has this capability. You are probably getting a 404 if the server is not seeing the request.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for all your help! So I tried chrome's network tab in developer tools ( I didn't know that before), and found the POST status as "400 Bad request". I guess it is something to do with the format?

Comment: This is probably that you are not returning any data to the requester. You should at least return something using the resp. You can simply send an error code. You may not see your debug message also unless you have your logger configured to show all messages. Try a system.out.println or using something like logger.info instead of debug. It looks like your response is getting there but you are not responding with anything to the caller.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right, because I noticed the size of contents being 139B and 0B (the two rows that chrome's developer tool shows). But I was actually using "  this.collection.create(formData);" and the formData is displayed at the webpage so I assume it shouldn't be empty. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: I think you are getting the 400 because you are not responding to the client. You should see my answer below. If you do this it will respond to the client with 200 response and the text hello world. The response is 0 bytes and this is wrong. Try the solution below and let me know.

Comment: I added your code into the doPost function of the servlet. It still gets the same result. Am I doing that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe URL called should include the context path, i.e. the path under which the application is deployed. This is usually the name of the folder that contains the application or the name of the WAR file, without the `.war` extension. So if your application is located in the folder `xxx.war`, try `url: "/xxx/todo"`.

Also check with Firebug to see the exact URL that gets called and the response from the server.

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Thank you very much Nikos Paraskevopoulos, for saving me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Send something back to the caller so that it will get a response of 200.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("Hello World");
```

Comment: I added to TodoServlet's doGet and still got the same error. Am I doing anything wrong? How can I check to which servlet the GET and POST send to? thank you!